# Loading Larga data to amazon sagemaker notebook

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-sagemaker, large-data

I have 2 folder, on each folder I have 70 csv files each one with a size of 3mb to 5mb, so in general the data is like 20 millions rows with 5 columns each.

I used amazon wrangler s3.read_csv to load just one folder with all the 70 csv to a dataframe, not sure if this is a good approach due to the fact the data is really large.

I want to know how can I load the entire csv files from those 2 folders with aws wrangler s3.readcsv, or should I use pyspark?

Also another question is, is it possible to work locally using amazon sagemaker depenencies? I am not sure if using sagemaker notebook for the pipeline development might cost a lot for my client.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PySpark to load data into your notebook as well, see [this repo](https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-studio-emr/blob/main/interactive_notebooks/local-pyspark-smstudio.ipynb) for instructions.

As for SageMaker, you can use the [SageMaker Python SDK](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), or [Boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html) to run jobs from your local machine. You can also create a notebook instance with a small instance size, experiment on a subset of your data, and trigger a [Processing job](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/processing-job.html) to keep your notebook costs low. You only pay for the duration your processing job runs, and you can scale up for preparing the entire dataset.